# Different behaviour of people search in different site collection

Tags: 2007, alert, sync

This is the scenario: 
Moss 2007 on a domain, user in a different trusted domain
E-Mail field has been manually populated (no exchange server on the user domain)
AD crawled successfully, browsing users shows the work email (mapped by default to the adsi field mail) 
two site collection: On one site collection all users receive email alerts, on onother site collection only some of the users does not receive the alerts. If i go to site settings>permission>add users and the I browse AD users I have a different behaviour on the two site collections, on the site collections where everything works find indeed I have the work email field filled, on the site collection where we have the issue is not present doing the same things (site settings>permission>add users) and people does not receive emails.

Any help is appreciated.

**Comment Added after first reply:**
Hi, Thanks for the quick reply! 
Indeed there were some and I followed what you suggested:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>stsa
dm -o sync -listolddatabases 0

Shared Service Provider SharedServices1
ID: a371227b-1d41-4d89-adad-1ca79c677738  Synchronized: 5/12/2010 9:00:00 AM
ID: 3bbeffaa-a7c1-48e5-947f-2038a4423c24  Synchronized: 10/21/2009 12:00:01 PM
ID: ba372cd5-463e-4f49-a7d9-76453e26c3dc  Synchronized: 1/11/2010 5:00:00 PM
ID: 3cc6fa54-05e4-471d-ac27-9af69707c244  Synchronized: 10/21/2009 11:00:01 AM
ID: 9e083125-b436-4e70-9178-acff30761e07  Synchronized: 7/7/2010 5:00:01 PM
ID: dc43a018-4ffe-497b-82cb-ae7bec20e82b  Synchronized: 10/21/2009 11:00:01 AM
ID: 3dec52a9-639d-41bd-834e-ca8ed6d80118  Synchronized: 7/7/2010 5:00:01 PM
ID: d8e32e9f-c3c6-4d65-8341-df85bf02ce0b  Synchronized: 7/7/2010 5:00:02 PM
ID: 096eb912-58bb-4c28-88ed-eb21059e88b3  Synchronized: 10/21/2009 11:00:03 AM
ID: de1c0ed8-b13b-46ea-a96a-fe7c9c6684ea  Synchronized: 7/7/2010 5:00:02 PM

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>stsa
dm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0

Deleted sync information for DB a371227b-1d41-4d89-adad-1ca79c677738
Deleted sync information for DB 3bbeffaa-a7c1-48e5-947f-2038a4423c24
Deleted sync information for DB ba372cd5-463e-4f49-a7d9-76453e26c3dc
Deleted sync information for DB 3cc6fa54-05e4-471d-ac27-9af69707c244
Deleted sync information for DB 9e083125-b436-4e70-9178-acff30761e07
Deleted sync information for DB dc43a018-4ffe-497b-82cb-ae7bec20e82b
Deleted sync information for DB 3dec52a9-639d-41bd-834e-ca8ed6d80118
Deleted sync information for DB d8e32e9f-c3c6-4d65-8341-df85bf02ce0b
Deleted sync information for DB 096eb912-58bb-4c28-88ed-eb21059e88b3
Deleted sync information for DB de1c0ed8-b13b-46ea-a96a-fe7c9c6684ea

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>stsa
dm -o sync -listolddatabases 0

Shared Service Provider SharedServices1
No databases match the criteria for this Shared Service Provider

Now shall I try or shall I force a sync somehow ?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!!!!!!!!!

http://www.4ward.it/Blogs/Systems-and-Web/July-2010/Sharepoint-Site-collection-out-of-sync-with-Active.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you added the email did you do it in the central user profiles or in the user information list for a specific site collection?  If you did it on the user profiles the updates should push out to the site collections.  You can check to see if the syncs are running by running the following command:

stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0

If there are any sites listed then you should run the following command.

stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0

Comment: Done... Now ? Shall I try to sync them somehow ? The issue is still there

Comment: Sorry for not specifying... this will reset it so that it will pick up the changes the next time the timer job runs.  This process happens I believe every two hours by default and is separate from any synchronizing your do between AD and the User profiles.

Answer (score 1):

No good news... sync is still not working, got the same behaviour. I also tried -IgnorIsActive 1 but no luck, any other suggestions ?